# Vue Router fullPath lost on web browser refresh

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vue-router

Versions:

```
"dependencies": {
  "@types/node": "^16.7.4",
  "core-js": "^3.6.5",
  "vue": "^3.0.0",
  "vue-class-component": "^8.0.0-0",
  "vue-router": "^4.0.0-0",
  "vuex": "^4.0.0-0"
},
```

So I've been building an SPA online portfolio in Vue3 and I've been faced with this problem since the beginning. I use the current route to trigger a transition on my HeaderComponent. That part's not important, really.

Whenever I navigate to `/`, `this.$route.fullPath` looks normal.

However, if I go to one of the other routes on my app, for example `/webdev`, and then I refresh, and check `this.$route.fullPath` again, it has `/` instead of `/webdev` like I expected it would.

So, as long as I don't refresh, the Header transition works as intended; however, the second I refresh on a route that isn't `/`, Vue Router forgets where I was and instead thinks I'm at the base path `/`.

`src/router/index.ts`

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from "vue-router";
import Home from "../views/Home.vue";
import WebDev from '../views/WebDev.vue';
import SoundDesign from '../views/SoundDesign.vue';

export default createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(),
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'Home',
      component: Home,
    },
    {
      path: '/webdev',
      name: 'Web Dev',
      component: WebDev,
    },
    {
      path: '/sounddesign',
      name: 'Sound Design',
      component: SoundDesign,
    },
    {
      path: '/:catchAll(.*)*',
      name: 'Home',
      component: Home,
    }
  ],
});
```

`src/App.vue`

```
<template>
<div class="page-container">
  <div class="content">
    <HeaderComponent :condenseHeader="condenseHeader"></HeaderComponent>
    <main>
      <router-view v-slot="{ Component }">
        <transition
          name="fade"
          mode="out-in"
          @before-leave="beforeLeave"
          appear
        >
          <component :is="Component"></component>
        </transition>
      </router-view>
    </main>
  </div>
  <FooterComponent></FooterComponent>
</div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from 'vue';

import HeaderComponent from './components/HeaderComponent.vue';
import FooterComponent from './components/FooterComponent.vue';

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    HeaderComponent,
    FooterComponent,
  },
  data: () => ({
    condenseHeader: false,
  }),
  beforeMount() {
    this.setCondenseHeader();
  },
  methods: {
    beforeLeave() {
      this.setCondenseHeader();
    },
    setCondenseHeader() {
      this.condenseHeader = this.pathNotHome;
    },
  },
  computed: {
    pathNotHome() {
      return this.$route.fullPath !== '/';
    },
  },
});
</script>
```

I've already tried both types of History in the routes file, as I've read that the HTML5 Browser History mode can cause 404's with things on reload, but I'm not getting a 404 - the page content remains as it did before the reload, but `this.$route` seems to reset or error out, or something.

Unless I'm doing something wrong, I'm surprised this is a bug in Vue as of now.

Comment: @Phil it's been happening both on my localhost and on the site itself. so, local and production

Comment: are you following the fallback setup which the docs says? https://next.router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I have a `catchAll` route in my routes file. I have no backend Node/Express setup like the page has, though. I didn't know it was needed for what I was doing.

Comment: @Phil Yeah, when i run the repo locally. I have no Node/Express server code - just this repo. I didn't know it was needed.

Comment: @Phil yes, I run the repo locally with `npm run start`. I get the refresh problem locally as well as up on the live site, which is `zachsmith.dev`. I don't really have any server configuration. I deploy the site through netlify.

Comment: @Phil here's the link to my repo in case you have further questions about how it's set up. Nothing but frontend.
https://github.com/ZekeHD/PortfolioWebsite

Comment: Regarding server configuration, if you're deploying to Netlify, I believe your `_redirects` file is [all you need](https://next.router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#netlify) so you should be good on that front

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is all to do with timing.

You're setting `condenseHeader` initially in your `App` component `beforeMount` hook. My guess is that when this hook fires on initial page load, the route path has not been resolved.

What I would do instead is make `condenseHeader` reactive by making it a computed property

```js
computed: {
  condenseHeader () {
    return this.$route.fullPath !== '/';
  }
}
```

Also, as per [Prop Casing (camelCase vs kebab-case)](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-props.html#prop-casing-camelcase-vs-kebab-case), your `condenseHeader` attribute should be `condense-header`...

```html
<HeaderComponent :condense-header="condenseHeader" />
```

Comment: Wow. I really think that did it. Ay ay ay. I never considered it could be a timing issue. Thank you so much, Phil. Question - would a computed property or a watch property be better here? I'm not doing an calculations or transformations, instead I'm just watching a specific value.

Also, duly noted on the kebab-case comment. I'll go back and change all the attrs in my repo.

Comment: I think the general consensus is to prefer computed properties over watchers (at least it was in Vue 2). In any case, given you want to use the result of the comparison in your template, I think that's a perfect use-case for computed

Comment: Gotcha. I'll go with a computed property for this, then. Issue solved. Thanks again!